# How to use Web services in .Net

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have requirement to fetch images and data from US based client's server then do work on it and then again save data on there server.
How do I start work on it.

Comment: Start by adding a Service Reference to your project and explore the methods the webservice offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow below for link for ur answer

http://www.wcftutorial.net/How_to_create_RESTful_Service.aspx